# Binding a whole native Activity to Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

So, I have a certain activity coded in pure Android that I want to use in my Xamarin.Android project. I compiled the activity into a ".jar" file, created a binding project, referenced it and so far everything was working. But when I try to create an intent to navigate to that activity, it returns an error:

```
System.TypeLoadException

Could not resolve type with token 01000013 (from typeref, class/assembly BR.Com.MyProject.Project.UI.SignUpPageActivity, MyBindingProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

Anyone have any clue on how to fix it? The binding is working fine, because along the activity I bound a few other classes, and they are all working, the only exception is when I call the "typeof()" method.

I've searched the whole documentation and found nothing about.

My Metadata.xml:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='br.com.myproject.project.ui']/class[@name='SignUpPageActivity']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Code calling the activity:

```
    public void NavigateToSignup()
    {
        Context context = Application.Context;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(SignUpPageActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What does the C# binding of SignUpPageActivity look like? Are you using using MonoAndroid or XAInterop1 for your code generation target? And what API level is the exception happening on?